# Linux: Computer crashed during moving Files

Tags: linux, crash, file-transfer

Short:
How to recover when crashing during filetransfer between partitions.

I created a complex portable installation of TexLive and a few utillities which in sum turned out to be 7+GB.
Now I needed some space so I decided to move my portable-folder to a Windows partition with drag+drop.
Roughly in the middle of it, my system crashed and I had to reboot.

Are my files OK? Can I just continue moving the rest?
I mean it's ext-4 on debian (source) and ntfs on Windows10 (target). Is ext-4 keeping partially copied files save?

It's a few hundred thousand files, so i can't go through and check individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that with a drag + drop of a large quantity of files, the links to all the individual files are  kept in memory. Maybe that has caused the system crash?

I would use **rsync** to move large files or large quantities of files from one computer to another. It is very efficient, fast and will only transfer the changes in files.

More info about rsync: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync

Comment: Thanks @pe7er . I know about rsync and in hindsight I would have used it. However I had been distracted at the time, by students asking questions. Do you know if one can check if the files are ok or corrupted? For otherwhise I'd have to redo the Installation and setup, which was quite some work.

Comment: Just use rsync and redo the copying. Rsync will only synchronize the remote files that are different (e.g. corrupt or missing) from the source files.

Comment: Thanks @pe7er . accepted.